# (Linear algebra) Is my proof correct?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a vector space of finite-dimensional space over complex numbers.
Let $T$ be a linear operator over $V$.
Show that if every eigenvalue of $T$ is $0$ then $T$ is nilpotent.

Proof

Let $\lambda$ be a eigenvalue of $T$, $v$ a corresponding eigenvector, then

$Tv=\lambda v$

$T^mv=\lambda^m v$

$0=\lambda^m v$

thus

$\lambda^m=0$

$\lambda=0$

therefore the eigenvalue of T is 0

Comment: I thought you wanted to show that if every EV is zero, that $T$ is nilpotent, but your proof ends with the conclusion that the EV of $T$ is zero?

Comment: You proof shows nilpotence implies eigenvalues zero. By your question, you prove the other part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $m$ be the minimal polynomial of $T$. Then $m(T)=0$. Because the field is complex, $m$ has a complete factoring
$$
      m(\lambda)=(\lambda-\lambda_1)^{r_1}\cdots(\lambda-\lambda_n)^{r_n}.
$$
It follows that every $\lambda_k$ is an eigenvalue of $T$ because
$$
    (T-\lambda_k)\left[(T-\lambda_1)^{r_1}\cdots(T-\lambda_k)^{r_{k}-1}\cdots(T-\lambda_n)^{r_n}\right]=0
$$
and
$$
   \left[(T-\lambda_1)^{r_1}\cdots(T-\lambda_k)^{r_{k}-1}\cdots(T-\lambda_n)^{r_n}\right] \ne 0.
$$
If every eigenvalue of $T$ is $0$, then $m(\lambda)=\lambda^m$ for some $m$, which forces $T^m=0$, which means that $T$ is nilpotent.

Comment: Are you using the Cayley-Hamilton theorem?   Does $(T-\lambda)$ mean $(T-\lambda I)$?

Comment: There is an annihilating polynomial for $T$; you can use basic dimension counting, or invoke Cayley-Hamilton, but the latter is not necessary. There is a monic polynomial of lowest order that annihilates $T$, and this is the minimal polynomial.

Comment: Thanks for answering about Cayley-Hamilton; and $(T-\lambda)$ means $(T-\lambda I)$?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner : Yes, $T-\lambda)$ means $T-\lambda I$.